# Urldecode русского текста

Tags: php

Помогите декодировать строку :

```
%D0%9F%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%
```

`urldecode()` не справляется :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Скорее всего вы выводите результат не в виде UTF-8 (а закодированная строка наверняка именно в этой кодировке);
2. В приведенном примере не хватает еще одного байта;

Comment: Браво, и спасибо. Скрипт  ограничивал длину строки, потому и заблудился.